# Launch activity from main activity and return to main activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to launch an activity from main activity and return to main activity after an exit operation in sub activity return to main activity?

I have made the sub-activity as launcher intent activity. So after installing the application i have two icons in applications menu, one for main activity and another for sub activity.

Please help me resolve the above issue.

Comment: Removed the intent-filter from your manifest saying DEFAULT in the second activity declaration , then when you have finished with your second activity call finish();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use only one activity as launcher intent in manifest.xml. Assuming that main activity is the launcher intent, from here you call `startActivity(Intent)` to get to the next activity. When the job performed by the sub activity is finished, call `finish()` to bring the main activity back to foreground

Answer (score 0):

Add finish in all others activities, when you'll return, main activity will be called

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
// To Kill the intent 
finish();
```

Sorry for my bad english !